How to compare two images in numPy arrays to get the pixels in which they are diffrent
I have two images in NumPy arrays, one of a game with no charecters on it and then another with charecters on it and then compare the two images to get a new NumPy array with just the pixels which are diffrent from the reffrence essentially removing the background from the image with the charecters on it.
The code below was my idea on how to do it but it doesnt work and im assuming it can be optimized to not use a for loop. the reason it doesnt work is that it throws an error saying
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (576,3) into shape (3,)
occuring in this line of code: result[i] = y
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
class filterImages:
    def subtractImage(self, bg, image):
        bg = cv.imread(bg)
        image = cv.imread(image)
        result = np.array([])
        i = 0
        for x, y in zip(bg, image):
            result.resize(i+1,3)
            if (x == y).all():
                z = x-y
                result[i] = z
            else:
                result[i] = y
            i = i + 1    


IIUC you can do:
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_1 = cv.imread("python_1.png")
img_2 = cv.imread("python_2.png")

out = np.zeros_like(img_2)

mask = img_1 != img_2
out[mask] = img_2[mask]

cv.imwrite("python_out.png", out)

The input:
python_1.png

python_2.png

The output:
python_out.png


This works pretty well but is their anyway to give it a margin of error so it  will be able to black out colors that are for example 1 rgb value away from the bg?

@Elisha Rather than defining the mask by inequality (as proposed in the answer above), you could define a threshold on the RGB values and then check whether the distance (e.g. sum of absolute differences) for each pixel is above or below the threshold. For example, threshold = 5; mask = np.sum(np.abs(img_1 - img_2), axis=-1) > threshold
